# Strange interaction between amsmath and setspace

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, superscripts, setspace

Compiling the MWE below, you will observe in the output the following phenomenon (you may have to zoom in):

- Comment `amsmath` out. Then, the spacing beteen lines is such that the subindex of the first line is not too close to the superindex of the second line, **whatever the settings of** `setstretch`.
- Now, load `amsmath`. Then, for `\setstretch{1.0}` and `\setstretch{1.05}` line spacing is again automatically adjusted so as to ensure that subindices of the first line do not get too close to superindices of the second line. **BUT** with `\setstretch{1.15}` the subindex of the first line almost overlaps the superindex of the second line.

Hope it's clear what I mean.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.0} 
%\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.05}
\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.15}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
XXXXXXXXXXXX $\Omega^{(\alpha,N)}_{\textup{brannnnnnnn}}$ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXXXX $\Omega^{(\alpha,N)}_{\textup{bran}}$ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{document}
```

---

Am I having hallucinations or is there a strange behaviour?

PS: There are no such problems with the following code:

---

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.0}
%\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.05}
\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
XXXXXXXXXXXX $\Omega^{(\alpha,N)}_{\textup{bran}}$ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXXXX $\Omega^{N^{N^{N^N}}}_{\textup{bran}}$ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without `amsmath, `\lineskip` is used because the lines are too near to each other. This doesn't happen with `amsmath` that changes the behavior of `\textup`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\showoutput` and you will see that the `\textup` text changes from 10pt to 7pt, you have indirectly loaded `amstext` which makes `\text....` commands respect subscript and reduce font size rather than acting like `\mbox` and always using the text size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.0} 
%\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.05}
\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\showoutput
\showboxdepth3


XXXXXXXXXXXX $\Omega^{(\alpha,N)}_{\textup{brannnnnnnn}}$ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXXXX $\Omega^{(\alpha,N)}_{\textup{bran}}$ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
\end{document}
```

You will see in the log

```
...\hbox(10.44443+3.01659)x345.0, glue set - 1.0 []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 0.33891
...\hbox(10.44443+3.01659)x345.0, glue set 9.70201fil []
```

which means that the expression was just small enough to squeeze into the normal baseline spacing. the actual skip that TeX inserts between rows is `\baselineskip` minus the depth of one row and the height of the next, which is just `0.3pt` here.

If you comment out `amsmath` you see

```
...\hbox(10.44443+5.09993)x345.0, glue set - 1.0 []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
...\hbox(10.44443+5.09993)x345.0, glue set 9.70201fil []
```

so here the expression is too tall to fit in normal baseline spacing so at this point TeX inserts `\lineskip` glue which unlike `\baselinesip` is a fixed value (1pt here) inserted to stop lines colliding.

Normally it is considered good practice to maintain an even line spacing, even if that makes things get close on occasion. If it is too close then you can play with `\lineskiplimit` which is the minimum space allowed before TeX switches to adding `\lineskip` glue to separate the lines. This defaults to `0pt`.

Comment: Actually I am using `\text` instead of `\mbox` precisely because it adjusts text size to super and subscripts! But I do not see how your answer explains the behaviour observed in my MWE!??

Comment: in the ams case the math display has smaller size (as it is using smaller fonts) so all the linespacing calculations are different. The actual formulas used are not changed by amsmath, it is just that the input to those formulae change.

Comment: OK, but **1)** (loading `amsmath`) why does line spacing work properly with `setstretch{1}` and `setstretch{1.05}` but not with `setstretch{1.15}` and **2)** is there any solution to the problem, I mean loading `amsmath` and using `setstretch{1.15}` and nonetheless having correct adjustment of line spacing so as to avoid super- and subscripts getting too close?

Comment: annotated log output added to answer

Comment: Thanks. The edited answer is extremely informative!! Now I really understand how it works ;-) Is there any way to tell LaTeX that at a particular instance it should reserve more vertical space for an expression? The point is that I have this "problem" only in the symbol index where naturally symbols appear "one over the other".

Comment: you can increase lineskiplimit just locally inside your index

Comment: `\index{\lineskiplimit5pt$\Omega^{(\alpha,N)}_{\textup{bran}}$}` doesn't have any effect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4512/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-lpdbw)